# is it possible to run python code outside of electron application

Tags: javascript, python, electron, bots

So I created a desktop electron application with javascript html css etc I have a bot that I want to run when a button is clicked by the user the bot is written in python. what the bot does is web scraping using selenium and chrome driver im just wondering is there a way where I could store the bot and its source code outside the clients computer so the source code is not visible and still give the client the ability to use the bot to webscrape.

sorry if this is a rookie question im coming from c++  & swift mobile development and im a junior CS student so im just teaching myself new stuff.

Comment: That is absolutely possible, you have to turn your python code into a public-facing web server though. You can use flask for that, but you also need hosting.

Comment: @ChrisG by public facing web server what exactly do you mean and hosting you mean like heroku or AWS right. So the electron app using flask would talk to the server and run the code from there to access chromedriver?

Comment: Well, regardless of the involved languages, if you want to hide your scraping code from the user, you need to put it on a web server, then make requests to the server from your electron app. Your python code is doing the scraping, so you might as well extend it to also be a web server. I.e. a flask app that includes your bot is hosted on the server. This could work maybe? https://www.pythonanywhere.com/

Comment: yea I was wondering if the requests on the server can run on the clients computer so open chrome driver on their computer.

Comment: `if the requests on the server can run on the clients computer` ...? I don't think you can have the python bot "outside" the client's computer and the chrome scraping process "inside". The idea is that the electron app makes a request to the python-based server which then does the scraping; the result is delivered back as response to the request. Also: why exactly do you want to hide the scraping code from the client? And what are you scraping in the first place? This might all be a massive [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: this is a bot for getting limited items  such as concert tickets but competition would probably like to get access to your code.  only thing is ik other business such as cybersole aio are able to do it I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Chris G in that it would be considered best practice to create a web app with one of Python's many web frameworks (Django, FastAPI, Flask, etc).

Alternatively, with the [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) package this can be done quite simply with electron:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const pyshell = require('python-shell')

function createWindow() {
  window = new BrowserWindow({ width: 600, height: 450 });
  window.loadFile('index.html');
        
  pyshell.run('your_script.py', function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/techiediaries/python-electron-app)

Then, with a simple python script `your_script.py`:

```py
a = 'Foo'
b = 'Bar'
print(a + b)
```

This example is quite simple. Creating your own web facing API would be your best bet if you don't want to run into any compatibility issues when shipping your app.

Comment: okay so pyshell is the alternative method but you suggest using flask or Django on my electron app connect with the python code which would essentially be hosted on a server of some sort?

Comment: @RayRay correct. Creating a web facing application and then rendering it within your electron app would be best. Alternatively, you can create an API (I suggest FastAPI) that runs your python script. This would be great if your script has additional parameters to be passed in.

Comment: ive already created my app using html ,css, javascript I wouldn't need to change the whole app right just implement and add the api. I would probably go with your recommended fast api due to the fact that I will be needing to pass in parameters to the python code. Thank you!

Comment: @RayRay You wouldn't have to change much – just a few simple ajax calls in your html/js using jQuery that would send a request to the API. While FastAPI is great, it does take a bit of time to learn. Flask, however, has thousands of tutorials for building an effective REST API. I'd definitely consider your options here and try to weigh out the pros and cons of each. Good luck!

Comment: @RayRay, looking at the other comment thread, I'm not too sure an API would be able to handle ChromeDriver too well, if at all. It would get quite tedious trying to solve your problem. Pythonanywhere wouldn't work for in this case – you would need to bundle your python app as an actual application. You could create a CLI, create a GUI, but that runs the risk of compatibility issues. Look into PySimpleGUI or PyQt5. That should give you a better idea of where to start.